# Синхронизация клиента и сервера при помощи именованого канала

Tags: c, pipes, fifo

Есть код (пример) program.c

```
    #define path "/sdcard/somepipe"

  int main() {
    mkfifo(path, 0777);
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file!\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Some text");
    sleep(3);
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Some text");
    sleep(3);
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Some text");

    printf("done\n");
    fclose(f);
  }
```

Данный код должен посылать текст клиенту и клиент его должен отображать СИНХРОННО каждые 3 секунды.
Порядок действий в Linux консоли.

`~$ ./program`

Сервер ждёт клиента и.

`~$ cat /sdcard/somepipe`

Текст начинает отображаться, НО проблема в том, что он отображается не синхронно, а только происшествии 6-и секунд и весь сразу, то есть как только сервер полностью отработал, получается.

Как сделать так, чтобы клиент получал и отображал, соответственно, данные каждые три секунды, а потом завершал работу вместе с сервером.

Comment: Небось, `flush()` надо дергать?

Comment: Поподробней, если можно.

Comment: `FILE *` буферизует вывод. Функция `fflush()` принудительно выталкивает содержимое буфера.

Comment: Спасибо, а без ffush-а никак?

Answer (score 1):

Протестировано:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define path "somepipe"

  int main() {
    mkfifo(path, 0777);
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file!\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Some text");
    fflush(f);
    sleep(3);
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Some text");
    fflush(f);
    sleep(3);
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", "Some text");
    fflush(f);

    printf("done\n");
    fclose(f);
  }
```

Только вот команды тестирования надо выдавать в обратном порядке:

```
cat somepipe &
./a.out
```